# Glassfish javax.ejb.EJBException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-4

I have problem trying to deploy Java Enterprise web application with EJB and JSF web module. 
Application builds successfully but when it gets deployed to Glassfish 4 server, I get this exception

```
javax.ejb.EJBException
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2009)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1979)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy325.vratiSveRelacije(Unknown Source)
at kontroler.KontrolerPrevoznika.vratiSveRelacije(KontrolerPrevoznika.java:275)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:326)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:536)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:136)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked recently with EJB and I can tell you to check the JNDI that you are setting to connect to the EJB.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "*hostname*");
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "*3700*");//default port
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
FirstBeanRemote bean = (FirstBeanRemote) ctx.lookup("java:global/*EARNAME/EJBJARNAME*/FirstBean!*fullyqualifiedpackage*.FirstBeanRemote");
```

1. The most important thing is to check if you are setting the
   **ctx.lookup** argument.
2. Check also the EJB jar if is deploying correctly.
3. I don't know If its a bug, but in Eclipse and Glassfish, The EJB can't have external jars

Comment: Sorry if it's a dumb question, but where this code should be? I'm really a beginner with java ee

Comment: Well, I suppose you have two projects, a client or consumer (could be a web project or a desktop app) and an EJB project, this code should be in the client or consumer side. Why? Because this code looks up for a connection that is outside the client

Comment: I have JSF and EJB modules inside Enterprise Application but I don't know where to put code like this. Should it be in Configuration files or in Source packages or somewhere else.

Comment: I assume you have .xhtml or .jsf files communicating to a Managed Bean, you can start your tests inside a Managed Bean. At the end the code that I suggest you can be executed from a Java class so If you are with JSF, use a Managed (Backing) Bean or if you want to test from a desktop application, put the code inside a main method.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem. My exception looks:

```
    javax.ejb.EJBException
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
```

And that because my EJB method throws an exception declared in another .jar file used by application as external library and that .jar library is in domain1/lib directory.

Try to throw another exceptions from EJB method and you will see the result.

Comment: I'n getting the same error. Can u please tell me how do u solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it turns out that the cause was in Payara/Glassfish, not in the app.
The admin portal - http://localhost:4848/ asked for login credentials all of a sudden, that was not the case before.
Setting up a new domain / glassfish instance resolved this issue for me. Might not work for everybody, but I hope it will save some of you some time.